# Accepting only a single character in a row in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string formatted like `Bananas|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Oranges|Green Apples|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Oranges|Red Apples|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Oranges|Pears` with a regex, on the `|||` or `|,|` delimiters. I'm using `[a-zA-Z |]+\|[,|\0]\|`, but I have a small issue: the triple-pipe delimiter is captured by the `[a-zA-Z |]` character class.

Is there a way to change the `[a-zA-Z |]` character class to only accept one pipe character in a row, while allowing any number of the other ones? (I.e. it should accept `accessories|batteries` but not `accessories||batteries`.)

More example: out of the original string, the regex should accept `Bananas|Oranges|,|` or `Bananas|||`, not `Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|,|`, with any number of single-pipe delimited names before the `|[,|]|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want a group containing a bunch of these `[a-zA-Z ]+` always followed by a `\|`. The group can repeat many times, and is always terminated by `,|` or `||` (after trailing `|`) so `(,|\|)\|`

Altogether: `([a-zA-Z ]+\|)+(,|\|)\|`

Comment: That will not work, as that would expect the first character to be a |. However, it should be allowed anywhere in the searched text.

Comment: I have updated the question with more-concrete accept/reject examples from the input string.

Comment: I think your examples clarify things a bit more - how about `([a-zA-Z ]+\|)+(,|\|)\|`

Comment: @Billy I didn't know you could nest a character class in a capturing group like that. How many levels out can you go?

Comment: I have never thought there is a limit to nesting. Maybe another question for stack overflow (google first). I checked the second regex against your test string and get: `"Bananas|,|", "Bananas|||", "Bananas|Oranges|,|", "Bananas|||", "Bananas|Oranges|||", "Bananas|Oranges|Green Apples|,|", "Bananas|||", "Bananas|Oranges|||", "Bananas|Oranges|Red Apples|,|", "Bananas|||", "Bananas|Oranges|||"` which I think is what you are after. I am updating my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using Java, an alternate approach would be to compute:

```
s.replaceAll("|||", "|,|").split("|,|");
```

where s is your starting string.

Comment: True, that would work, but the difference between `|||` and `|,|` is significant. I could replaceAll to something completely different (like `|;|`), though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a non-greedy quantifier on your regular expression? That way it will stop at the first `|||` or `|,|` that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, but why can't you do a straight split using a regex == `\|\|\||\|,\|`? Here is a tested script that works for me:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String subjectString = "Bananas|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Ora" +
        "nges|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Oranges|Gre" +
        "en Apples|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Orange" +
        "s|Red Apples|,|Bananas|||Bananas|Oranges|||Bananas|Ora" +
        "nges|Pears";
        String[] splitArray = null;
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\|\\|\\||\\|,\\|");
        splitArray = regex.split(subjectString);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < splitArray.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(splitArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

`Bananas`
`Bananas`
`Bananas|Oranges`
`Bananas`
`Bananas|Oranges`
`Bananas|Oranges|Green Apples`
`Bananas`
`Bananas|Oranges`
`Bananas|Oranges|Red Apples`
`Bananas`
`Bananas|Oranges`
`Bananas|Oranges|Pears`

Comment: Then I wouldn't know if the sections ended in `|||` or `|,|`.

Comment: CajunLuke, you should add that detail to the description of your problem.  Usually, no distinction is made between delimiters, and the delimiter is not included in the result.